# ZF2, Apigility with Doctrine and Embedded Atributes issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I'm trying to fetch some data using two nested queries through two doctrine repos:

```
$user = $this->_objectManager->getRepository('\Application\Entity\User')->
findOneBy(array("hash" => $data));
$id_user = $user->getId();
$user_credits = $this->_objectManager->getRepository('\Application\Entity\UserCredits')->
findOneBy(array("user_id" => $id_user));
return $user_credits;
```

I apply some Hydrators in the module.config.php:

```
'Application\\Entity\\User' => array(
                'entity_identifier_name' => 'id',
                'route_name' => 'client-api.rest.getcredits',
                'route_identifier_name' => 'getcredits_id',
                'hydrator' => 'Zend\\Stdlib\\Hydrator\\ArraySerializable',
            ),
            'Application\\Entity\\UserCredits' => array(
                'entity_identifier_name' => 'credits',
                'route_name' => 'client-api.rest.getcredits',
                'route_identifier_name' => 'getcredits_id',
                'hydrator' => 'Zend\\Stdlib\\Hydrator\\ArraySerializable',
            ),
```

And in each doctrine Entity I configure the getArrayCopy() like this:

User:

```
public function getArrayCopy()
    {
        return array(
            'id'=>$this->getId(),
            'phone'=>$this->getPhone(),
        );
    }
```

UserCredits:

```
 public function getArrayCopy()
    {
        return array(
            'id'=>$this->getUser(),
            'credits'=>$this->getCredits(),
        );
    }
```

And here is the result:

```
{"credits":100,"_embedded":{"id":{"id":10,"phone":123456789,"_links":{"self":{"href":"http:\/\/testserver.test\/getcredits\/10"}}}},"_links":{"self":{"href":"http:\/\/testserver.test\/getcredits\/100"}}}
```

But I actually would like a result something like:

```
{"credits":100,"id":10},"_links":......
```

**How can I make this possible?
Why ID is embedding into it?**

Answer (score 0):

It is embedded because you return an object.

```
'id' => $this->getUser()
```

In this case `id` will be an object of type `User` and that object will render embedded because of the `extractEmbeddedEntity` method being called inside the `renderEntity` method of the `Hal` plugin

Simply change to:

```
'id' => $this->getUser()->getId()
```

and you will get the result you want.